# CSS underline paragraph with no text

Tags: html, css

I want to underline a paragraph with a specific width even when there's no text. Is that possible?
My css paragraph class:

```
 width: 100px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, transparent 19px, #333 20px);
    text-align: center;
```

I got this from another question posted here but the problem is that it wont be underlined if there's no text.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: make code snippet with full code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5d8sv3h5/2

Answer (score 2):

Try using `

```css
p{
    width: 300px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<p></p>
```

`

Comment: @JoelSuter Can you see two underlines in the above solution?

Comment: what do you mean? if you mean my "solution" there's even three underlines if there's no text

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS border-bottom property to add an underline to any HTML element. Actually, it's not really an underline. It's simply a border that runs along the bottom of the element. Here's an example:

```
<p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">This paragraph has a bottom border.</p>
```

I think this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
<p class="MyP">&nbsp;</p>
```

For reference : https://plnkr.co/edit/QfXSzWlcfbvgxePKOqLU?p=preview?

Comment: that works but then the text won't be exactly in the right place

Comment: Sorry dear I am not getting.
Use Javascript to replace the content of <P> 
edit the plnkr and send the link

Comment: here you can see it wont work with no text/space: https://plnkr.co/edit/6keCU4ICL85HTQrswENW?p=preview

Comment: It won't work because browsers just ignore empty paragraph tags. So for it's rendering you have to put something inside it. In this case we are putting a blank invisible character